# How do you post a comment in excel only using the keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

To begin a comment, it's easy enough: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. What I can't figure out is how to post the comment using the keyboard. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> just exits without posting the comment and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> just goes to the next line within the comment.

How do I do post the comment without having to use the mouse to press the green button?

Note: I am not trying to use notes (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>), which you can post fully with the keyboard by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>. I am specifically asking about comments.

Comment: Have you tried alt+enter / ctrl+enter?

Answer (score 1):

One method I just figured out is to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the post button and then click <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I won't be accepting this answer yet in case there is a one key press solution.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> will commit the comment.